# "Property Images does not exist"

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I get the "Property Images does not exist" for an old project that I opened today with Delphi Tokyo 10.2 Trial.

How to (re)produce it:
Select multiple controls on a form (at design time). At least one of the controls needs to have an 'Images' property. For example, I select with Shift+Click a TLabel and a Tbutton.

For the button I see its 'Images' property listed in Object Inspector. And it seems to work ok: I can assign a list of images to it.

So, what is the actual problem? Why do I see this error (ONLY when I select multiple controls)?

---

```
[5011EB3F]{rtl250.bpl  } System.TypInfo.PropertyNotFound (Line 1126, "System.TypInfo.pas" + 1) + $21
[5011EBEA]{rtl250.bpl  } System.TypInfo.FindPropInfo (Line 1160, "System.TypInfo.pas" + 3) + $6
[5011ED11]{rtl250.bpl  } System.TypInfo.GetObjectProp (Line 1210, "System.TypInfo.pas" + 1) + $8
[157A850D]{dclQuickEdit250.bpl} Quickedit.TQuickEditor.GetVerb + $1FD
[157A8729]{dclQuickEdit250.bpl} Quickedit.TQuickEditor.PrepareItem + $E1
[525BE924]{vcldesigner250.bpl} VCLSurface.AddSelectionVerbs (Line 2717, "VCLSurface.pas" + 15) + $14
[525BEB8B]{vcldesigner250.bpl} VCLSurface.TVclDesignSurface.BuildLocalMenu (Line 2771, "VCLSurface.pas" + 9) + $1
[21F6AA6C]{delphicoreide250.bpl} PropInspManage.TDesignerPropSelection.GetHotCommandMenuItems (Line 331, "PropInspManage.pas" + 3) + $13
[21F6BCF7]{delphicoreide250.bpl} PropInspManage.TDesignerPropSelection.UpdateHotCommands (Line 690, "PropInspManage.pas" + 2) + $C
[21F6B602]{delphicoreide250.bpl} PropInspManage.TDesignerPropSelection.SelectionChanged (Line 597, "PropInspManage.pas" + 15) + $2
[2120B4DF]{designide250.bpl} ComponentDesigner.DesignNotificationSelectionChanged (Line 8832, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 5) + $A
[21206B24]{designide250.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentDesigner.SetSelection (Line 7021, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 20) + $5
[212070AA]{designide250.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentDesigner.UpdateSelections (Line 7089, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 19) + $C
[21206841]{designide250.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentDesigner.RootActivated (Line 6941, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 5) + $2
[525D04A2]{vcldesigner250.bpl} VCLFormDesigner.TVCLRootDesigner.Activate (Line 344, "VCLFormDesigner.pas" + 4) + $1E
[525C0BB6]{vcldesigner250.bpl} VCLSurface.TVclDesignSurface.IsDesignMsg (Line 3584, "VCLSurface.pas" + 114) + $A
[5005FBA2]{rtl250.bpl  } System.@IsClass (Line 17427, "System.pas" + 1) + $8
[50AC499B]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7239, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $21
[211AEFCA]{designide250.bpl} DeskUtil.SetFocusHook (Line 463, "DeskUtil.pas" + 4) + $C
[50AC97FB]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10197, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 166) + $6
[50AC8DC8]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9896, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[5016EBC4]{rtl250.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 17406, "System.Classes.pas" + 9) + $2
[50C119C7]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10596, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 6) + $9
[50C11AB2]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10643, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50C11DE5]{vcl250.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10781, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
[005088E2]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 212, "" + 7) + $7
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing and what triggers this error. Can you describe in more detail, please?

Comment: @UweRaabe - question updated

Comment: Submit a bug report to Embarcadero. I don't think there's anything that we can do.

Comment: The same bug on selecting multiple objects. Old project opened in 10.2 Tokyo

Comment: Also happens here with Shift+mouse selections, sometimes also with Shift+click selections too. This is really annoying. I'm also reluctant in submitting a bug to QC as they never ever fixed any bugs that I reported.

Comment: @pbu - It happens also in C++ Builder Tokyo after update 3

Comment: @djsoft - I also stopped LOOOOOOONG time ago wasting time with reporting bugs to Embarcadero. Better fix it by yourself. Never rely on Emba to fix bugs. I am really pissed that for Delphi xe7 they released a patch but I HAVE TO PAY to get it!!!! Since when people have to pay money to have bug fixed. We pay for the software not for the bugs!

Comment: related: https://www.delphipraxis.net/195712-[ide-bug]-image-property-does-not-exist.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a "Known bug".
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19984

Type: Bug
Status: Open
Priority: Major Major
Resolution: Unresolved
Affects Version/s: 10.2 Tokyo Release 3, 10.2 Tokyo Release 2
Fix Version/s: None